# Fitting a markov chain with markov chains of different lengths

Tags: r, markov-chains

I am trying to fit a markov chain to web sessions. Those obviously have different lengths. Below is the code that I tried, but it doesn't work and I suspect it might be because the sessions are of differing lengths. Can someone please help me diagnose and fix the problem?

```
library(markovchain)

mc_data <- aggregate(sessions[c("session_id","cs.uri.stem")], by=list(sessions$"session_id"), FUN=c)["cs.uri.stem"]
mc <- markovchainListFit(mc_data, byRow=TRUE)
```

Test data for the aggregated data (already aggregated):

```
   Group.1 session_id               cs.uri.stem
1        1    1, 1, 1 /, /, /1127_about-us.aspx
2        2       2, 2    /, /1127_about-us.aspx
3        3          3                         /
4        4          4                         /
5        5          5                         /
6        6          6                         /
7        7          7                         /
8        8          8                         /
9        9          9                         /
10      10         10                         /
```

What I am getting as error is this:

> Fehler in data[, c(i - 1, i)] : Indizierung außerhalb der Grenzen

Error in English (Google translate):

> Error in data [ c (i - 1, i )]: indexing outside the boundaries